# Using CSS to truncate both sides of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that is coming from an iframe.  I need to truncate out both the left and right side of the div.

For example, this div is 200 pixels.  We only want the *middle* 100 pixels.  The left 50 pixels and the right 50 pixels are meaningless.

here is my unsuccessful test:

```css
div#parent {
        border: 2px dotted blue;
        max-width: 100px;
    }
    div#child {
        border: 2px solid orange;
        left: -50px; left
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden ;
        max-width: 200px;
        min-width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id='parent'>
        <div style='text-align: center;' id='child'>
             this div will contain a clickable iFrame
        </div>
    </div>
```

This almost works, except the iFrame is not cooperating and covering elements to the left. Using a negative z-index works very well, but it disables the iFrame click-able elements.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: where did you set the negative z-index? the child div or the iframe?

Comment: Make sure your overflow property is on the parent div -- nothing is supposed to be overflowing in the child!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've got `overflow: hidden` put on the child div, but it really belongs on the parent. The `overflow` property dictates how to display the overflowing *contents* of the element, not it's own overflow.. So putting that style on the parent instead will hide anything sitting outside of it's edges, inside of it.

Comment: thank you!  it worked perfectly with the iFrame and clicking.